# Why is my SwiftUI List populating with the same item 4 times instead of all 4 items?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, combine, swiftui-list

I'm reading data from Firestore and parsing it to a custom model `Thought`

For each document in my Firestore collection I append a new `Thought` object to a `@Published var thoughts`.

```
struct Thought: Identifiable {

    public var id: String?
    public var name: String
    public var thought: String
    public var color: String
}

class Observer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var thoughts = [Thought]()

    init(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("thoughts")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            for document in documents {

                var thoughtModel = Thought(id: "", name: "", thought: "", color: "")

                thoughtModel.name = document.data()["name"] as! String
                thoughtModel.thought = document.data()["thought"] as! String
                thoughtModel.color = document.data()["color"] as! String

                self.thoughts.append(thoughtModel)
            }
            print(self.thoughts) //PRINTS 4 DIFFERENT THOUGHT OBJECTS
        }
    }
}

struct ThoughtsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observer = Observer()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.observer.thoughts) { thought in

                    ThoughtCard(color: thought.color,
                                thought: thought.thought,
                                name: thought.name)
                    //HERE I GET THE SAME CARD 4 TIMES INSTEAD OF 4 DIFFERENT CARDS
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I print `thoughts` I'm seeing all 4 documents that are currently in my Firestore database. However, when I try iterating through `thoughts` in my list I just the same `Thought` object 4 times instead of 4 different `Thought` objects.

I think the problem lies within the `List` and how I'm iterating through `self.observer.thoughts`, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I populate the list with the 4 objects in `self.observer.thoughts`?

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed a problem with my List. Once I added the `id:` parameter it looks like List was able to identify each `Thought` object and display them accordingly.

```
struct ThoughtsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observer = Observer()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.observer.thoughts, id: \.name) { thought in

                    ThoughtCard(color: thought.color,
                                thought: thought.thought,
                                name: thought.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```